# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i'm New in Javascript

Code :-

```
$('#similar-artist').append('<div class="chip" data-uuid="'+ item.artist_id +'" >'+ item.name  + '  ' + if (item.last_name){ item.last_name }else{}  +'</div>');
```

Errore :- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'`

Thank You

Comment: You cannot just stick an `if` statement into the middle of an expression.

Comment: try item.last_name ? item.last_name : {} or item.last_name  ?? ""

Comment: Can you add some line breaks to your code to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the conditional operator instead, because it resolves to an *expression* (`if` cannot be used in an expression context):

```
+'" >'+ item.name  + '  ' + (item.last_name ? item.last_name : '') +'</div>'
```

That's for the general case - you can alternate between `item.last_name` and `''`. If you want to interpolate something only if it's truthy, like here, you can use `||` as a shortcut:

```
+'" >'+ item.name  + '  ' + (item.last_name || '') +'</div>'
```

But, even better, consider using a template literal instead, for improved readability:

```
const html = `<div class="chip" data-uuid="${item.artist_id}">${item.name}  ${item.last_name || ''}</div>`;
$('#similar-artist').append(html);
```

Also keep in mind that concatenating arbitrary HTML is a potential security risk. Unless the `item` is coming from a secure, trusted source of your own, you might want to do:

```
$(`<div class="chip" />`)
  .attr('data-uuid', item.artist_id)
  .text(`${item.name}  ${item.last_name || ''}`)
  .appendTo('#similar-artist');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use if-else in a string expression,

change `if (item.last_name){ item.last_name }else{}`  to `(item.last_name ? item.last_name : '')` as the later one return a string, equivalent to the string expression